# Git stuck on "command not found" after bad commit message

Tags: zsh

After a bad commit message with a lack of quotes, I cannot commit anything to git.  How do you exit this loop?

What happened:

```
(.venv) admin@jps-MacBook-Pro CUBoulder-CSPB3308-Team-0-Project % git commit -m added add_baby() func to sql_functions.py

(.venv) admin@jps-MacBook-Pro CUBoulder-CSPB3308-Team-0-Project % git status

git:7: command not found: func

(.venv) admin@jps-MacBook-Pro CUBoulder-CSPB3308-Team-0-Project % git commit -m "added add_baby() func sig to sql_functions.py, built more 
testing data"    

git:8: command not found: func

(.venv) admin@jps-MacBook-Pro CUBoulder-CSPB3308-Team-0-Project % git status

git:9: command not found: func
```

Comment: Does Ctrl+C help? If not, close the terminal window and open a new one.

Comment: What shell are you using? It looks like whatever shell you're using treated `func` after parentheses as a keyword. zsh might do this, in which case you have a zsh question, not a Git or terminal question.